# Use Jinja's groupby filter with tuples

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I'm building a Flask app with Jinja2 templates and feeding it data from Flask-SQLAlchemy. I want to build a view (list effectively) based on a query that gives me a tuple with two objects (`User` and `Registration`):

```
eligible_racers = db.session.query(User, Registration).filter(User.id==Registration.racer_id).filter(Registration.team_id==team_id).filter(Registration.season_id==race.season_id).all()
```

In my template I'd like to group the results by an attribute of the `Registration` object. The [`grouby`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#groupby) filter seems ideal, but it doesn't seem like there's a way to pass it an attribute of one of the tuple members.

Is there an elegant way to do this in my template? Or do I need to do the grouping in my Python view code and pass the template differently structured data (keeping in mind I need to keep the users and registrations paired)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Jinja filters, including `groupby`, handle multiple levels of attribute lookup by separating the attributes with `.`.  SQLAlchemy queries returned keyed tuples with the name of the selectable (the model in this case) as the attribute name.

```
{% for level, items in racers|groupby('Registration.level') %}
    {{ level }}
    {% for user, registration in items %}
        {{ user.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You could also use `1.level`, index lookup works too.